# How can I forward jquery requests from my server directly to another?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I have a web client, ShazamClient, from which which I want to use jQuery to get data from and post data to a remote web api, ShazamService. At first I tried POSTing directly to ShazamService in jQuery, but got errors related to CORS, which is not enabled on ShazamService. So to work around, I want to forward the request directly from either a `Controller` or `ApiController` of ShazamClient to the corresponding method call in ShazamService. So I basically want:

```
public class ShazamClientController : ApiController // or Controller
{
    public string Upload()
    {
        return Request.Forward(@"https:\\shazamservice.com\api\upload");
    }
}
```

Most of what I find online relates to redirects, etc - is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: does ShazamService support jsonp? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: I've read that jsonp only supports GET (maybe outdated info?) Either way, I find it cumbersome - HTTP error don't trigger the jQuery 'failure' handler, or even the 'complete' handler; they just die quietly.

Comment: yeah, I'm not suggesting jsonp is a good alternative, just throwing it out there to see if it met your needs

Comment: It's a good suggestion, happens to not seem right in my case though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and reuse the content sent to your controller to make a request to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you "proxy", here's one trivial example with `WebAPI`

HTML/Web Page:

```
<h1 id="dataTarget"></h1>

<script>
....
//Because Web API wants it's own "keyless" format for [FromBody] data (=value)
var _data = { "": "data foo" };

$.post("api/values", _data, function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    $("#dataTarget").text(d.foo + ' ' + d.bar); 
 });

</script>
```

Slightly modified default scaffolding of `WebAPI ValuesController` action using `[FromBody]` :

```
// POST api/values
public async Task<JObject> Post([FromBody]string value)
{           
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        /*
         * See http://www.jsontest.com/#echo for usage
         *  which serves as the "other" service you are "proxying"
         *
         *  Echoed values will be used in front end html
         */
        return JObject.Parse(await client.GetStringAsync("http://echo.jsontest.com/foo/hello/bar/world"));
    }
}
```

The "magic" of `WebAPI`:

[image: Headers inspection]

Hth...